# Web proxying with 3rd party authentication

Tags: networking, nginx, proxy, haproxy

I have a typical website where users have to pay to sign up and access some premium content. This content are internal propietary web servers from different vendors (think of it like graphical management interfaces for some devices).

These web interfaces are not accessible from outside by default, so I have to put a web proxy in front of the website in order to proxy the requests depending of the URL. For example:

```
http://example.com --> ok (public server)
http://example.com/settings --> ok (public server)
http://example.com/resource1 ---> proxy to web server running on 10.0.0.20 (LAN)
http://example.com/resource2 ---> proxy to web server running on 10.0.0.30 (LAN)
```

This is quite straight forward using HAProxy or nginx for example. The problem is that, you should not be able to get that http://example.com/resource1 URL without being logged in the main website, otherwise everyone would benefit from that without signing up.

The main problem is that there is no way (that I could find) to see if the user is logged in the main website from the proxy pov. I have created an API in the main website where you can verify if the cookie is an active session. I thought that I could use this somehow with the proxy, but I cannot find a way to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a shared database and cookies.

The workflow can be this way:

1. Unauthenticated ser connects to `http://example.com/resource1`.
2. A file added on every php page checks the session, detects an unauthenticated user, and redirects to `http://example.com/login.php`.
3. User enters login/password, and a session key is added to the database. User is redirected to `http://example.com/resource1/?session=$PHPSESSIONID`.
4. The same file on step 2 checks the session against the database and validates the user.

Comment: This is a valid approach when you have control over the application. These running servers are propietary applications that can't be touched, so it's not an option unfortunately. The check must be done somewhere else (in nginx somehow for instance).

Answer (score 0):

With nginx you can allow or deny access in a location block basing yourself on the result of a subrequest.

```
location ~ /resource[1-2] {
    auth_request /authenticate;
}
```

If the subrequest returns codes 2xx then access is granted. If the subrequest returns 401 or 403 then access is denied.

Make sure your nginx binary has been compiled with the `--with-http_auth_request_module` option.